# How to fill left over space regarding Layout Managers?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I recently have been developing a Swing application. I have run into a problem with Layout managers. I can't seem to figure out how to make components in the layout grow all the way to the edge of their parent container. Let me explain.

Say I have 8 buttons all in one row. Depending on the window size will determine if they take up all the space. GBL I have found centers so both space on left and right. BoxLayout usually space on the right side. This is probably due their anchors or alignment.

I think the problem is because the Layouts when all components have same settings it tries to give each component same space. So that little extra space can't be divided up equally to each component they leave it out.

I was wondering if there was a work around for this. Like the space is so small I was hoping there was a way to make last component eat it up or divide it best it can between the components.

Here is example code showing the problem. Note when you resize the panel you get extra space.

```
public class LeftoverExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                LeftoverExample.createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createGUI(){
        JFrame jF = new JFrame();
        jF.setSize(new Dimension(1333,500));
        jF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create ContentPane
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        GridBagLayout gBL = new GridBagLayout();
        gBL.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
        gBL.rowHeights = new int[]{50, 50, 50 , 50};
        contentPane.setLayout(gBL);

        //Initial Constraints
        GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gBC.gridx = 0;
        gBC.gridy = 0;
        gBC.weightx = 1;
        gBC.weighty = 0;
        gBC.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);

        //Add Examples to ContentPane
        contentPane.add(LeftoverExample.createGBL(false), gBC);
        gBC.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(LeftoverExample.createGBL(true), gBC);
        gBC.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(LeftoverExample.createBoxLayout(false), gBC);
        gBC.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(LeftoverExample.createBoxLayout(true), gBC);

        //Final
        jF.setContentPane(contentPane);
        jF.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JComponent createGBL(boolean addButtons){
        //GBL Example
        JLabel gBLJLabel = new JLabel("GridBagLayout");
        gBLJLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        gBLJLabel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gBLJLabel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        gBLJLabel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        gBLJLabel.setOpaque(true);
        gBLJLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        GridBagLayout gBL = new GridBagLayout();
        gBL.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
        gBL.rowHeights = new int[]{50};
        gBLJLabel.setLayout(gBL);

        //Initial Constraints
        GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gBC.gridx = 0;
        gBC.gridy = 0;
        gBC.weightx = 1;
        gBC.weighty = 0;
        gBC.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //Add to GBL Panel
        if(addButtons){
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(gBLJLabel, gBC);
        }
        return gBLJLabel;
    }

    private static JComponent createBoxLayout(boolean addButtons){
        //BoxLayout Example
        JLabel boxLayoutJL = new JLabel("BOX_LAYOUT");
        boxLayoutJL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        boxLayoutJL.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxLayoutJL, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        boxLayoutJL.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        boxLayoutJL.setOpaque(true);
        boxLayoutJL.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        //Add to BoxLayout Panel
        if(addButtons){
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(boxLayoutJL);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(boxLayoutJL);
            LeftoverExample.addButtons(boxLayoutJL);
        }
        return boxLayoutJL;
    }

    private static JButton createButton(Color c){
        JButton jB = new JButton();
        jB.setBackground(c);
        jB.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        return jB;
    }

    private static void addButtons(JComponent jC, GridBagConstraints gBC){
        //Create Buttons
        Color[] colorA = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN};
        for(Color c : colorA){
            jC.add(LeftoverExample.createButton(c), gBC);
            gBC.gridx++;
        }
    }

    private static void addButtons(JComponent jC){
        //Create Buttons
        Color[] colorA = {Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
        for(Color c : colorA){
            jC.add(LeftoverExample.createButton(c));
        }
    }
}
```

See how each West and East side there is some space left that the parent (in this case JLabel) takes up but the buttons don't. I want to be able to have the buttons take up that space as well.

Picture showing example:

[image]

Comment: I can't test or analyze your code as I'm using a tablet, but usually empty Jlabels are used when a blank placeholder is needed.

Comment: In the code posted the buttons grow  in width and fill the parent frame. Isn't that what you wanted ? (side note: remove `static` from all methods and create an instance of `LeftoverExample`)

Comment: To clarify, is the question "how do I get rid of the space at the start and end when resizing?"

Comment: I'll redo my example to show the problem better. But for now it is the left over space the buttons don't fill. If you just have 1 button in the layout it will take up all the space. When you keep adding more buttons to the layout depending on the ratios of the buttons you will have extra space.

You can greatly see this with more buttons.

I'll also try to provide pictures of the problem (that show the left over space I'm talking about). @c0der

Comment: There is only a very small horizontal gap, or are you talking about vertical gap ?

Comment: The problem is most likely due to Swing dimensions being integer and not double precision. If you manually calculate and set the `JButton` size when the `JFrame` is resized the same problem exists. The more components you add, the more noticeable this will become. Perhaps consider using JavaFX? Somebody may have a solution, but even adding `Box.createHoriztonalGlue()` between the `JButton` objects won't help.

Comment: I updated the example and added a picture.

I'm a bit too deep to switch to JavaFX haha, appreciate the comment explaining the problem @d.j.brown

Comment: @c0der I updated my example code and also included a picture

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I updated the code and included a picture showing the problem better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by Swing using integer values for dimensions rather than double.

Taking this fact into consideration, the remainder *r* of the division of the containers width divided by the number of `Component` (in your case `JButton` objects) objects it contains can be used to increase the size of the first *r* `Component` objects by 1 to compensate. Obviously this means the first *r* `Component` objects will be +1 larger than the other `Components`, but this should not be noticeable.

In order to update the width of the `Component` objects we need to have access to there container (e.g. `JPanel`) and all the `Component` objects we wish to update. In my example, I will use a `List` for this purpose.

Here is a method to do the work of resizing the `Component` objects accordingly.

```
private static void fixComponentWidths(Component container,
    List<? extends Component> componentList, int componentHeight) {

    if (!componentList.isEmpty()) { // Avoid possible division by zero

        // get the desired component width for the container using integer division
        int baseComponentWidth = container.getWidth() / componentList.size();

        // find the remainder
        int remainder = container.getWidth() % componentList.size();

        // update all the components
        for (int i = 0; i < componentList.size(); i++) {

            // the component width will be the base width plus 1 iff i < remainder
            int componentWidth = baseComponentWidth;
            if (i < remainder) {
                componentWidth++;
            }

            // update the maximum size
            componentList.get(i).setMaximumSize(new Dimension(componentWidth, componentHeight));
        }

        // be sure to revalidate otherwise it may not work
        container.revalidate();
    }
}
```

In order for this to work on resize, a `ComponentListener` must be implemented for our container. This could either be the `JFrame` or just a `JPanel` (as per my example). Note, only the `componentResized(ComponentEvent)` method needs implementing for this task.

```
buttonContainer.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) { // just implementing this
        fixComponentWidths(buttonContainer, buttons, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        // where buttonContainer is a JPanel,
        // buttons is a List of JButtons
        // BUTTON_HEIGHT, well the height of the button!
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) { // not needed
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) { // not needed
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent ce) { // not needed
    }
});
```

That is all that is needed. But for completeness here's a small example, based on the author's question, followed by a subclass of `JPanel` which uses a `BoxLayout` that can be used to resolve this behavior for both `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` and `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`.

**Complete example**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FillExample extends JFrame {

    private static final int FRAMEL_DEFAULT_WIDTH = 700;
    private static final int FRAME_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 400;

    private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    private final List<JButton> buttons;

    public FillExample() {
        buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void createAndShow() {
        setTitle("Fill Example");
        setSize(FRAMEL_DEFAULT_WIDTH, FRAME_DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        final JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
        buttonContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonContainer, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            addButtons(buttonContainer);
        }

        getContentPane().add(buttonContainer);

        buttonContainer.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
                fixComponentWidths(buttonContainer, buttons, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void fixComponentWidths(Component container, List<? extends Component> componentList, int componentHeight) {
        if (!componentList.isEmpty()) {
            int baseComponentWidth = container.getWidth() / componentList.size();
            int remainder = container.getWidth() % componentList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < componentList.size(); i++) {
                int componentWidth = baseComponentWidth;
                if (i < remainder) {
                    componentWidth++;
                }
                componentList.get(i).setMaximumSize(new Dimension(componentWidth, componentHeight));
            }
            container.revalidate();
        }
    }

    private void addButtons(JComponent component) {
        Color[] colorA = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN};
        for (Color c : colorA) {
            JButton button = createButton(c);
            buttons.add(button);
            component.add(button);
        }
    }

    private static JButton createButton(Color color) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBackground(color);
        button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, BUTTON_HEIGHT));
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FillExample().createAndShow();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**FillBoxLayoutPanel**

This small class can be used to quickly resolve this spacing issue for both `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` and `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`. Note, that the class create the `BoxLayout` and the `LayoutManager` cannot be changed.

`Component` objects can be added to the panel using `add(Component comp)` and `add(Component comp, int index)`. Note, not all `add` methods are overridden, the class should be used carefully.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FillBoxLayoutPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final int X_AXIS = BoxLayout.X_AXIS;
    public static final int Y_AXIS = BoxLayout.Y_AXIS;

    private final List<Component> components;

    private final int direction;
    private boolean layoutSet;

    public FillBoxLayoutPanel(int direction) {
        components = new ArrayList<>();
        this.direction = direction;
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, direction));
        layoutSet = true;
        addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
                adjustComponents();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }

            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }

            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent ce) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayout(LayoutManager mgr) {
        if (layoutSet) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("FillPanel's layout manager cannot be changed.");
        } else {
            super.setLayout(mgr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Component add(Component comp) {
        comp = super.add(comp);
        components.add(comp);
        return comp;
    }

    @Override
    public Component add(Component comp, int i) {
        comp = super.add(comp, i);
        components.add(i, comp);
        return comp;
    }

    private void adjustComponents() {            
        if (!components.isEmpty()) {
            int size = direction == X_AXIS ? getWidth() : getHeight();
            int baseComponentSize = size / components.size();
            int remainder = size % components.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
                int componentSize = baseComponentSize;
                if (i < remainder) {
                    componentSize++;
                }
                Dimension dimension;
                if (direction == X_AXIS) {
                    dimension = new Dimension(componentSize, components.get(i).getHeight());
                } else {                    
                    dimension = new Dimension(components.get(i).getWidth(), componentSize);
                }
                components.get(i).setMaximumSize(dimension);
            }
            revalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great job @d.j.brown; I already applied your concept of taking the remainder left and divvy up to the components, and works flawlessly with BoxLayout (as you have shown in your example code as well). I have seen camickr response and now debating whether adding another Utility method to my project and fix all my BoxLayout and GridBagLayout (GBL I could take your concept and apply it to grid) or replace all BoxLayout with Relative Layout and still create Utility method for GBL...

Comment: @BWCsemaJ hopefully the idea is helpful. I've added a small subclass of `JPanel`  that can be reused for `BoxLayout` layouts. I would look at `GridBagLayout` as well, but maybe another day.

Answer (score 2):

> I think the problem is because the Layouts when all components have same settings it tries to give each component same space. So that little extra space can't be divided up equally to each component they leave it out.

Maybe you can use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/).

It allows you to easily make each component the same size.

It then has a property that allows you to determine how extra pixels should be allocated if needed.

Comment: I was not aware of this Layout Manager. Heaven knows why this or something similar wasn't added to the AWT/ Swing libraries. +1 for englightneing me.

Comment: @camickr, I see how your answer would solve all my BoxLayout issues (just replace BoxLayout with Relative...), but what would you advise regarding GBL. I really am fond of GBL and I think I could take d.j.brown idea and apply it to GBL either with Utility method or extending GBL and applying d.j.brown solution, but I am not sure if that is a good idea in the long run. I already have some utility methods regarding GBL (flipping layout around and adding column/row with minimal size to GBL)...

Comment: @BWCsemaJ, Using utility methods to make it easier to apply constraints to a group of components is a common approach. However, I don't think using a component listener to "override" the sizes determined by the layout manager is the best approach in the long run. Now you have layout code in two places, one in the layout manager and one in the component listener. So my choice would be to customize GBL so all the layout code is in one place.

Comment: However, this really is a special requirement for a single row of components. A GBL is much more powerful than this, so I'm not sure how you would incorporated "rounding" considerations into the full complexity of the GBL.As I said at the start of my blog, I prefer using multiple simpler layout managers with minimal constraints to achieve a layout rather than trying to force a layout manager to do everything. Complex layout managers are used by IDE's because they can't think logically to break the layout down into smaller component groupings. What you prefer is your choice.

Comment: `I see how your answer would solve all my BoxLayout issues` - RelativeLayout is not designed to solve BoxLayout issues. BoxLayout does proportional resizing based on the size of individual components. I just suggested it could mimic a BoxLayout in the case where all components happen to have the save size. In general you should let each component determine its own preferred size. BoxLayout will then allow each component to grow proportionally. RelativeLayout ignores the preferred size and allow components to grow relatively.